# Unable to install owncloud

Tags: owncloud

I am trying to install and setup owncloud from the scratch. I followed the steps provided in https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.0/admin_manual/installation/source_installation.html#prerequisites-label

I have created the mysql user after installing Mariadb-server using following command

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
sudo mysql --user=root mysql
CREATE USER ADMIN@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'adminpass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *. * TO ADMIN@localhost WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit
```

I have tried both commandline installation wizard and graphical installation wizard.

Following is the command line install wizard command

```
sudo -u www-data php /var/www/owncloud/occ maintenance:install --database "mysql" --database-name "funocdb" --database-user "root" --database-pass "mysql"  --admin-user "ADMIN" --admin-pass "adminpass"
```

But I am getting the following error:

> ownCloud is not installed - only a limited number of commands are available
>
> Error while trying to create admin user: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Here the screenshot of 'occ' error

[image: occ error]

While trying the same with Graphical installation wizard, I got the following error:

> Error while trying to create admin user: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'ADMIN'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Here the screenshot of GUI error

[image: GUI error]

Comment: Are you able to connect manually to the database with the provided credentials?

Comment: Self explanatory no? You provided the wrong password for the admin user during setup. Try to login from the command line or recreate the user if you can’t log in

Comment: I can connect to the database manual through the terminal using command `sudo mysql -u admin -p`. 
But I am getting the error while setting up the owncloud.

Comment: @LelioFaieta , I am sorry I couldn't find. Which password is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By reading the comments I think you're mixing up the ownCloud's `--admin-user` and mySQL's "root" user ("`ADMIN`") since you mentioned that it works out using mySQL cli. From the command line, try using `--database-user "admin"` instead (also note that user names in mySQL can be case sensitive depending on your settings).

And from the web UI you can try to append mySQL's port no. (standard is 3306) to the host name, like the notice at the bottom of the screenshot says.

Answer (score 0):

Please access your database from mysqlworkbench or any mysql client and please go to owncloud database and alter oc_calendarsubscriptions.lastmodified to NN(Not Null)